# Need to refactor this JS, not sure where to start

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, refactoring

Just inherited this function for a dropdown menu and it's ugly as sin, and seems to be pretty fragile in several browsers(mostly older versions of safari), but Im not even sure where to start, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I need to break this into several smaller functions as well as remove the hard coded html(not sure exactly how to do that)

The offending code:

```
function mini_cart_populate(){
  var order;
  $.get('/get_current_order.json',
  function(data) {
    $('#minicart-thumbnails').html('');
    order = data.order;
     if (order.order.line_items.length == 1) { 
      $('#minicart_content').addClass('single'); 
      $('.cart_pulldown').addClass('single'); 
      $('#minicart_footer').addClass('single');
    } else {
      $('#minicart_content').removeClass('single');
      $('.cart_pulldown').removeClass('single');
      $('#minicart_footer').removeClass('single');
    }
    if (order.order.line_items.length > 0) {
      $('#cart_pulldown').removeClass('empty_minicart');
      $('#minicart_header').show();
      $('#minicart_content').show();
      $('#minicart_footer').show();
      $('.clearBoth').show();
      for (var i = 0; i < order.order.line_items.length ; i ++ ) {
        var char_limit = 80;
        var variant = data.variant_information[i];
        var item_string = "<div class='minicart_item_wrapper'>";
        //image string
        item_string += "<a href='"+ variant.path +"'><img src='"+ variant.image_url +"'></a>";
        //assume title and description for all items
        item_string += "<div class='mini_item_detail'>"+
          "<p class='mini_item_description'><strong>"+variant.title+
          "</strong>"+"<br/>"+variant.description.slice(0,char_limit)+
          (variant.description.slice(char_limit).length > 0 ? "..." : "" ) + "</p>";
        //assume all items have price
        item_string += "<li>"+"$"+Math.round(variant.price)+"</li>";
        //check for variant measurements and foreign sizes; add '|' if there are
         if (variant.variant_size) { item_string += " | <li>"+variant.variant_size+"</li>"; }
        if (variant.foreign_size) { item_string += " | <li>"+variant.foreign_size+"</li>"; }
        var delete_button_string = "<div class='cart-item-delete minicart' data-hook='cart_item_delete'>" +
           "<a href='javascript:;' class='delete' id='delete_line_item_"+ 
          variant.line_item_id +"' line_item_id='" + 
          variant.line_item_id + "'>X</a></div></div></div>" 
        if (window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] == "checkout"){
          delete_button_string = ''; 
         }
        $('#minicart-thumbnails').append( item_string + delete_button_string )
        bind_delete_button();
        $('#minicart_info').show();
        $('#minicart-thumbnails').show();

       }
    } else {
      $('.cart_pulldown').addClass('empty_minicart');
      $('#minicart_info').hide();
      $('#minicart-thumbnails').hide();
      $("#mini_empty_message").show();
      $('#minicart_header').hide();
      $('#minicart_content').hide();
      $('#minicart_footer').hide();
      $('.clearBoth').hide();
    }
     set_product_page_variant_state();
     var new_count = order.order.line_items.length + " item";
     if (order.order.line_items.length > 1) { new_count += "s" };
     $("#mini-item-count").text(new_count);
  }).done(function(){

    var item_total = parseFloat(order.order.item_total);
    var subtotal = item_total.toFixed(2);
    $('#minicart_subtotal').text('$' + subtotal);
  })
}
```

Comment: The first thing is to make your code easier to read to humans with http://www.jslint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by formatting the code properly and breaking it into its logical sections:

- The AJAX request
- Separate functions that do the DOM modifications
- A function that contains the for loop

So your function may start to look something like this instead:

```
function mini_cart_populate() {
    // I find the longhand ajax form more readable
    $.ajax(
        type: "get",
        url: "/get_current_order.json"
    ).done(current_order);
}

function current_order(data) {
    var order = data.order;
    if (order.order.line_items.length == 1) {
        add_single();
    } else {
        remove_single();
    }
}

function add_single() {
    $('#minicart_content').addClass('single'); 
    $('.cart_pulldown').addClass('single'); 
    $('#minicart_footer').addClass('single');
}

// ...etc, hopefully you get the idea
```

Sort out the formatting of the actual code as well: http://jsbeautifier.org/ will do some work for you, but you may have to finish it yourself. Opinions are divided on it, but I think you should camelCase your variable names in JS, especially if you are working with jQuery (as that's the jQuery functions in your code will look like). I find consistency makes JS easier to read.

You could build the HTML with jQuery, or you could look at a templating solution like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), or if you really want to sort it out, this looks like it comes from the kind of project that could do with a full refactor using an MVC library (e.g. [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) or [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)).

They may seem a little daunting at first, but you'll learn better practices in terms of application design and maintainability for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start refactoring code like this is to simply split it up.  Find a chunk of it that looks it preforms related tasks, and move it to its own function, then call that function.

For example:

```
order = data.order;
if (order.order.line_items.length == 1) { 
  $('#minicart_content').addClass('single'); 
  $('.cart_pulldown').addClass('single'); 
  $('#minicart_footer').addClass('single');
} else {
  $('#minicart_content').removeClass('single');
  $('.cart_pulldown').removeClass('single');
  $('#minicart_footer').removeClass('single');
}
if (order.order.line_items.length > 0) {
```

So we need to setup the cart differently, based on if there is one item, or more than item.

```
var styleCarFortLineItemQty = function(order) {
  if (order.line_items.length == 1) { 
    $('#minicart_content').addClass('single'); 
    $('.cart_pulldown').addClass('single'); 
    $('#minicart_footer').addClass('single');
  } else {
    $('#minicart_content').removeClass('single');
    $('.cart_pulldown').removeClass('single');
    $('#minicart_footer').removeClass('single');
  }
}
```

Now we can refactor the code in your huge function like so:

```
order = data.order;
styleCarFortLineItemQty(order);
if (order.order.line_items.length > 0) {
```

Do that a few times until you have a handful of functions with descriptive names, and you will then end up with a lean function that describes logic and flow, while other helper functions do the actual manipulation and work.

Once you get here, you can start doing more advanced refactoring, adjusting overall flow and logic.  But doing that before you fit the flow and logic in your head will lead to pain.